# Quick way to go to downloads from Chrome?

Tags: chrome-for-android

Often after downloading a file, I try to open this from the notifications page, only for the wrong app to open it. Since I've clicked on it the link has disappeared. Now I have to go through tonnes of menus to find the file! Is there a quicker way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the home screen, click the "all apps" button, then there's an app called **Downloads**. By default, downloads are sorted most-recent-first, so the one you've just downloaded will be at the top.

If even that method is one step too many, you can long-tap on the **Downloads** icon in the apps menu, then drop it on the home screen to create a shortcut to that app. Now you can open it from the home screen directly.

Additionally, if the wrong app opens a certain kind of file, you can stop that and go back to having a *chooser* to pick which app to open files with. Open the **Settings** app, then go to **Apps** (on some phones it's called **Applications manager**). Choose the offending app from the list: if it's a built-in app, you'll need to swipe to to the **All** page. Scroll down and click **Clear defaults**. Next time you open a file that would open with that app, you'll get the chooser instead (assuming you have another app installed that can open that kind of file).